Функция должна реорганизовать масив , переставив все нечетные в лево
Функция принимает массив целочисленных чисел, диапазон значений которых составляет от 0 до 100. В  функции нужно переставить элементы массива, так что в левой стороне были все нечетные числа а справа все четные. Например, массив 1, 4, 5, 8, 9 должен быть переписан на 1, 5, 9, 4, 8.
Код:
unsigned* segregateEvenOdd(unsigned array[], const  size_t size)
{

   for (int index = 1; index <= size; ++index)
   {
      if (array[index] % 2 == 0)
      {
        std::swap(array[index], array[index + 1]);
      }
   }
   array[size] = 0;
   return array;
}

int main()
{
    int size = 100;
    unsigned array[101];

    for (unsigned index = 0; index <= size; ++index)
    {
      array[index] = index;
    }
    std::cout << "segregateEvenOdd: " << segregateEvenOdd(array, size) << "\n";

    return 0;
}

Какой у меня вопрос:

Я не правильно массив в функции возвращаю? Потому что отображается следующее:
 segregateEvenOdd: 000000E9B9DEF9C8


Из -за того, что я не правильно возвращаю массив, я не знаю, правильно  ли  сделалала задания. Поэтому я буду рада советам о том, как улучшить мой код.

Почему то только один индекс берет и проверяет и меняет местами. Не переходит на слудещий:
Index:2
Index1:3
Index2:2




Важен ли порядок в переставленном массиве? Или надо только одно - чтобы нечетные были в начале, а четные в конце? Просто раз уж у вас С++, то есть масса готовых алгоритмов стандартной библиотеки, которые можно использовать. А выводить массив надо по одному элементу, например, с помощью цикла.

@Harry  думаю важен(

Тогда какой именно? Например, 3 4 2 1 5 6 — должно получиться 3 1 5 4 2 6, или 1 3 5 2 4 6? Или еще какой? Да, кстати, чтоб два раза не писать :) - массивы в С/С++ нумеруются не с 1, а с нуля!

@Harry Например, 3 4 2 1 5 6 — должно получиться 1 3 5 2 4 6

Т.е. части должны быть отсортированы?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition

@StanislavVolodarskiy Не годится: ТС требует сортировки... Я потому так настойчиво и выяснял о порядке, чтоб понять, можно ли partition использовать...

Ну, раз требуется полная сортировка, просто пишем соответствующую функцию-компаратор, которая сравнивает два числа с учетом четности:
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int array[] = {3,6,9,8,2,1,5,4,7};
    sort(array,array+size(array),
         [](int a, int b) {
             if (a%2 != b%2) return (b%2 < a%2);
             return a < b;
         });
    for(int a: array) cout << a << " ";
}

Ну, или, например, так:
bool compare(int a, int b)
{
    if (a%2 != b%2) return (b%2 < a%2);
    return a < b;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int array[] = {3,6,9,8,2,1,5,4,7};
    sort(array,array+size(array),compare);
    for(int a: array) cout << a << " ";
}


А если использовать дополнительный массив (интересно, сколько дополнительной памяти использует сейчас реализация sort?), то задача (с условием сохранения относительного порядка в массиве) решается за 2 прохода (на первом копируем в новый массив четные и переставляем нечетные, на втором копируем обратно четные)

@avp А за один проход слабо? Не думаю, что возврат того же самого массива - обязательное условие. Даже тот же массив можно вернуть, мне кажется.

Блин, да наверно за пол прохода можно! (В лучшем случае.)

@rotabor, за один никак не получится. Если вы имеете в виду алгоритм, что то вроде -- бежим вправо, как только нашли нечетный сдвигаем его перестановками влево, пока не упремся в ранее сдвинутые нечтеные -- так это сортировка вставками, а она вообще квадратична. А предложенная Harry сортировка N log(N)

@avp А если чётные вправо с конца записывать?

@rotabor, что с носа до хвоста, что с хвоста до носа -- один крокодил

#avp За один проход вписываем нечётные с начала нового массива, а чётные - с конца. Два сортирумых значения - два места. Это кардинально упрощает.

За один проход можно выполнить разделение четных и нечетных, но не сортировку (разве что потом прибегнуть к какой-то из O(N) сортировок, но у них обычно константы не самые маленькие...)

@Harry, алфавит маленький, можно обойтись сортировкой подсчётом.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Ну, это и есть "одна из" :) Но да, можно в один проход подсчетом, раз там всего от 0 до 100.
